# Dynamically select fields based on result object as a combination of base and derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've got a couple of classes I need to return data from.

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FilterCriteria1 { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string BestFriend { get; set; }
}
```

Based on return type I want to select all base fields plus derived class fields.

```
public class BaseResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BestFriend { get; set; }  
    //...many more base properties
}

public class CustomResult1 : BaseResult
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class CustomResult2 : BaseResult
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

SQL queries should look like this:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.BestFriend, p.Address FROM Person p LEFT JOIN AdditionalData a ON p.Id = a.PersonId WHERE p.FilterCriteria1 = 'X'
SELECT p.Name, a.BestFriend, p.Age FROM Person p LEFT JOIN AdditionalData a ON p.Id = a.PersonId WHERE p.FilterCriteria1 = 'Y'
```

The problem I face is, that I can't dynamically select the fields as a combination of BaseResult fields plus the derived class fields

I know that it would be possible to do something like

```
var query = from person in context.Set<Person>()
    join a in context.Set<AdditionalData>()
        on person.Id equals a.PersonId into a2
    from addtionalData in a2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new CustomResult1(person, additionalData);
```

and set the data in a custom constructor, but unfortunately this would select all fields which would slow down the query by a lot.

This doesn't work (result of my function is `IQueryable<BaseResult>`):

1. CS8514: An expression tree may not contain a switch expression

   ```
       join a in context.Set<AdditionalData>()
           on person.Id equals a.PersonId into a2
       from addtionalData in a2.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select typeof(BaseResult).Name switch
       {
           nameof(CustomResult1) => new CustomResult1 { }
       };
   ```
2. Is there a way to define fields in two steps?

   ```
       join a in context.Set<AdditionalData>()
           on person.Id equals a.PersonId into a2
       from addtionalData in a2.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new BaseResult { Name = person.Name //etc. };
       //cast to IQueryable<CustomResult1>, howto set fields of derived class, e.g. Address?
   ```